# Remmina - use client certificate

Tags: 18.04, windows, remote-desktop, rdp, remmina

I'd like to use Remmina client to connect to Windows Server on remote location. The provider supplied me with a client certificate and an RDP file.

When I click the RDP file Remmina not surprisingly vents its anger on me with "Authentication failed" message.

How can I use client CER certificate for the authentication in Remmina?